# How is a solid doughnut, a disk of circles?

Tags: general-topology

I understand how its a circle of disks but not how its a disc of circles. Solid doughnut = $D^2$ X $S^1$. Animation would elate me.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking; can you please clarify further, for example cite where you found this statement.

Comment: @William In a chapter on Products in 'The Shape of Space' by Jeffrey R. Weeks. For example it's easy to see that a cylinder is an interval of circles and at the same time a circle of intervals i.e Cylinder = $S^1$ X $I$.

Comment: Start with the disk in the $xz$-plane of radius $1$ centred at $\langle 2,0,0\rangle$. The circle in the $xy$-plane of radius $2$ centred at the origin passes perpendicularly through the centre of the disk. Let the disk travel along the circle in such a way that its centre always lies on the circle, and the disk is always perpendicular to the circle at their point of intersection. The disk traces out a solid torus, and each point of the disk traces out a circle. The solid torus is therefore a disk of circles, one circle for each point of the disk. See the sketch in **Donkey_2009**’s answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an animation, but I hope this gives you some of the idea.

[image]

For each point on the disc, we have a circle.  Taking the union of all the circles together gives us the solid torus.

In general, if $X$ and $Y$ are spaces, then their product $X\times Y$ is naturally homeomorphic to the product $Y\times X$ in the other direction.

Comment: Thank you very much. One more help! When I see it as a cicle of disks, I resolve disks arranged in circle but here its difficult for me to directly see circles arranged in disk!